# Infinite grid in Qt

Tags: qt, grid, qgraphicsview

I have created a grid in Qt of the size of graphics view. Whenevr I zoom in/out, the grid is visible in a small area. Drawing is possible in the entire area but grid is confined to a small area.

I have created the grid using the following code:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= ui->graphicsview->width(); x += 10){
    scene->addLine(x,0,x,ui->graphicsView->height(),QPen(Qt::green));
}
for(int y = 0; y <= ui->graphicsView->height(); y += 10){
    scene->addLine(0,y,ui->graphicsView->width(),y,QPen(Qt::green));
}
```

How do I make the grid infinite so that on zoom out, the grid still persists over the area equal to size of graphics view?

Answer (score 1):

The view is only the size of the "camera" looking into a fraction of the scene.  If the scene isn't populated with really long lines in all directions, it won't show up on the view when you zoom out.  Making the lines the size of the current view is almost worthless once the view changes.  Decide what "infinity" means for your application and add all the appropriate lines to the scene.  You may need a loading screen as your program is adding all of them.

Or you could do some lazy loading, where you only add the lines to the scene, as the view is panned or zoomed out.

Look into the example of the 40000 chips included with the Qt libraries to see how to do nearly infinite objects, and how to handle level of detail changes as you start to zoom out really far.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw "infinite" lines with the QGraphicsView framework.

Subclass the *QGraphicsView* or the *QGraphicsScene* and implement your grid drawing in the `QGraphicsView::drawBackground()` or `QGraphicsScene::drawBackground()`.

In the `drawBackground()` method you have to compute intersection points between exposed rectangle (the *rect* argument of this method) and your grid lines.

Then, use the `QPainter::drawLine()` with the computed intersection points to draw lines.

I know, this is quite brief explanation of the concept, but I hope it will help.
If not, I can explain it in detail.
 A couple years ago a was facing similar problem.